# Complete novice question: I want to delete a table via command prompt (postgis)

Tags: postgis, fme

I am a regular FME user and I know how to create a postgis database to be used in FME (using PGadmin). I now want to use FME to backup and then delete a generated table. I use the 'systemcaller' transformer for this, the systemcaller basically opens command prompt.

I was able to make a backup file using *cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\118\bin\ && set PGPASSWORD=password&& pg_dump.exe -U postgres -p 5433 -d bag -t tablename -F c -f C:/Users/username/Downloads/tablename.backup"*, but I am having a hard time getting the table to be deleted.

I tried the 'drop table' command, but this is not recognized. It will recognize drobdb, but I obviously do not want to drop the whole database.

What commandline should I use to drop te table 'testtable' in the database 'testdatabase'?

Comment: have you tried something like? `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\118\bin\ && set PGPASSWORD=password&& psql -U postgres -p 5433 -d bag -c  "DROP TABLE tablename;"`